# my data return after remove item in recyclerview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an app that one of the things it does is put items in a custom listview. Now I want to remove an item using setOnClickListener.
The item does disappear but the problem is that when I exit and open the app or scroll between tabs the items return to the custom listview.
Can anyone please help me?

activity

```
        loadData();

        mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mAdapter = new exampleAdapter(mExampleList);
        
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new exampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),show.class);
                intent.putExtra("Example Item", mExampleList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeleteClickListener(int position) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mExampleList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
        private void loadData() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preferences12", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list12", null);
            Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<exampleItem>>() {
            }.getType();
            mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
            if (mExampleList == null) {
                mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        private void buildRecyclerView(View view) {

        }

}
```

adapter

```
public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextViewLine1;
    public TextView mTextViewLine2;
    public TextView mTextViewLine3;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageView imageViewD;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView,final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextViewLine1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line1);
        mTextViewLine2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line2);
        mTextViewLine3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_line3);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icond);
        imageViewD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDdd);
        mRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);

        imageViewD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onDeleteClickListener(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to save list after removing item:

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    mExampleList.remove(position);
    // saving the list to shared preference:
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preferences12", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("task list12", new Gson().toJson(mExampleList)).apply();
    ///////////// end of saving
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```